# Connect to VM Host IP using Tor-Browser

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, tor

I am Using a VM with Tor-Borser (v8.5.4) installed. I have a node.js server running on my host. I can connect to this server using another Browser, e.g. Chrome, using the IP 10.0.2.2:.

However, using Tor, this is not possible. How do I have to configure the Tor-Browser, in order to be able to access this IP?

Comment: *"I can connect to this server using another Browser, e.g. Chrome, using the IP 10.0.2.2"* -- You mean that from your VM you can connect to Node on your host?

Comment: Yes, sotrry for the late reply, I figured it out. Just had to add 10.0.2.2 to the NoProxy exception.